# How can parsing code with PHP json_decode

Tags: php, json, xml

I need to parse this string and display the result.

**Sample**:

```
 "<string xmlns=\"http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/2003\/10\/Serialization\/\">
{\"response\":\"0\",\"errorMsg\":\"\",\"lstsmi\":[{\"code_bordereau\":\"111111111\",\"etat\":\"yes\"},{\"code_bordereau\":\"222222222\",\"etat\":\"yes\"}]}<\/string>"
```

**Code**:

```
$response = json_decode($get_data, true);

echo $response["lstsmi"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response string is in XML format and it has additional `\` marks firstly you should remove the `\` mark and use the PHP [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) method to read XML. so try the below code

```
<?php
$str="<string xmlns=\"http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/2003\/10\/Serialization\/\">
{\"response\":\"0\",\"errorMsg\":\"\",\"lstsmi\":[{\"code_bordereau\":\"111111111\",\"etat\":\"yes\"},{\"code_bordereau\":\"222222222\",\"etat\":\"yes\"}]}<\/string>";
$str=str_replace("\\","",$str);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

//as a xml
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
echo "<pre>";

//as a json
echo $xml[0];
echo "<br/>";

//as an array
$response = json_decode($xml[0]);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "<pre>";
```

result

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 
{"response":"0","errorMsg":"","lstsmi":[{"code_bordereau":"111111111","etat":"yes"},{"code_bordereau":"222222222","etat":"yes"}]}
)
{"response":"0","errorMsg":"","lstsmi":[{"code_bordereau":"111111111","etat":"yes"},{"code_bordereau":"222222222","etat":"yes"}]}
stdClass Object
(
    [response] => 0
    [errorMsg] => 
    [lstsmi] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code_bordereau] => 111111111
                    [etat] => yes
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code_bordereau] => 222222222
                    [etat] => yes
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because your code is not json format.
at first ,you have to clear your code.

try this one , I hope it could be helpful for you

```
<?php
$str = "<string xmlns=\"http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/2003\/10\/Serialization\/\">
    {\"response\":\"0\",\"errorMsg\":\"\",\"lstsmi\":[{\"code_bordereau\":\"111111111\",\"etat\":\"yes\"},{\"code_bordereau\":\"222222222\",\"etat\":\"yes\"}]}<string>";
    
@$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($str);
$real_json_string = $doc->textCotent;
$json = json_decode($real_json_string, true);
echo print_r($json);
?>
```